# Cumulative Count in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have email data that I am trying to put into a dashboard in Power BI

As an example, here is what I am looking to do. I want to take the following simple data:

1-Jan  open

2-Jan  open

2-Jan   click

2-Jan   open

3-Jan   click

4-Jan   open

And show a running count of the number of opens to look like so:

1-Jan  1

2-Jan  3

3-Jan  3

4-Jan  4

I am a relative beginner to Power BI and nothing I have tried so far has gotten me close. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not a well-formed question.  Refer to [ask].  And as of this writing, you didn't even bother to take the 2-minute site [tour].

Answer (score 0):

I would add a Measure using the DAX function: TOTALYTD, something like:

```
Running Count = TOTALYTD ( COUNTROWS ( 'My Table' ) , 'My Table'[My Date] )
```

Then I would add the Field containing open/click to the **Visual level filter** well for the visual you want to show in the dashboard, and Filter it to "open".

Comment: I should have mentioned this in the question: the date column and response column are from two different tables. The date column coming from a table containing every email that was sent out and the date of that email. The response coming from a table containing every email address that opened, clicked, unsubscribed, etc. I know it is  hard to perform row by row functions, but I am hoping to count the rows for every date that I pull into the table

Comment: haha just a minor detail ... you will need to find a column that is common to the 2 tables and a unique key to one of them, and use that to create a Relationship between the 2 tables.  With that in place, DAX functions can work across related tables.

Answer (score 0):

Add a measure to the table:

```
Cumulative Count = CALCULATE(COUNT('My Table'[Column 2]),FILTER(ALL('My Table'[Date Column]),'My Table'[Date Column] <= Max('My Table'[Date Column])))
```

This measure will calculate the cumulative value, which in turn can be used to generate the required table/graph